# Automatically resized imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a scrollView and imageView in it.
The app works in landscape and portrait mode.
And i use auto layout.
If i use constant for imageview.
images that I loaded into imageviev it automatically expands under its size.

What i have now:

Landscape mode:
[image]

and Portrait mode:
[image]

I want to make it as in these pictures

Landscape mode:
[image]

and Portrait mode:
[image]

How do I fix the auto resize in imageview?

P.S. App for iPad

Thank you all for answers!

Comment: Are you using Autolayout for portrait as well? It is not clear to me why you specify that you use Autolayout in landscape mode, when the whole idea of Autolayout is to make your app screen size and orientation independent.   If you are doing it programatically, can you post some code for us to check?

Comment: I use Autolayout for all orientations in interface builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of code based Autolayout that should help you

```
#import "UniversalViewController.h"

@interface UniversalViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *myImageView;
@end

@implementation UniversalViewController
@synthesize myImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Velvet_Underground_and_Nico.jpg"];
    myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    [myImageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
    [self setWidth:300 andHeight:300 toView:myImageView];
    [self centerView1:myImageView toView2:self.view];
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    [self centerView1:myImageView toView2:self.view];
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self setWidth:450 andHeight:250 toView:myImageView];
    } else {
        [self setWidth:300 andHeight:300 toView:myImageView];
    }
}

#pragma mark custom Autolayout methods
- (void) setWidth:(float)width andHeight:(float)height toView:(UIView *)view {

    NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
    myConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:width];
    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

    myConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:height];
    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
}

- (void) centerView1:(UIView *)view1 toView2:(UIView *)view2 {
    NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
    myConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

    myConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];
}
```

You should be able to set the size of the images as you require...   I hope it helps...